# Plex Media Server won't find media files

Tags: linux, arch-linux, plex

PMS on Arch won't find my media files. I can't think about anything else to say, but that I'm running PMS 0.9.16.4.1911-1 on Arch 4.4.5-1-ARCH.

One of my libraries is set to `/srv/plex/movies`. The directory and items in that directory are owned by `root:root` and are set to `777` (I am aware of the security complications), as well as `/srv` and `/srv/plex`. I have tried reinstalling and removing the configuration files.

Each movie is nested in its own folder, with the folder being named `Movie Title (Year)` as well as the movie itself, according to [Plex Support](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200381023-Naming-Movie-files).

[When running PMS manually](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Plex#Plex_Media_Server_.28PMS.29), I get this:

```
Error starting framework core for /opt/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-ee6e505/Fanart-TV.bundle.
Error starting framework core for /opt/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-ee6e505/LyricFind.bundle.
Error starting framework core for /opt/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-ee6e505/OpenSubtitles.bundle.
Error starting framework core for /opt/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-ee6e505/LastFM.bundle.
Error starting framework core for /opt/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-ee6e505/PlexMusic.bundle.
Error starting framework core for /opt/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-ee6e505/PlexMovie.bundle.
```

Logs are available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ckhmfh9hnbilwas/AACOHP2l6GGtHiZt-EqKr6Doa?dl=0). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One possible cause for this could be due to the system not being able to resolve its own host name. Did you check that?

Comment: I checked the hostname and it won't work.